# Why AzureAD expects estsrequest parameter in relay state for SAML IDP initiated workflow

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0, idp, symantec

We have created a new SAML connector using a generic template in Symantec VIP access manager. We have configured Azure AD as relying party(Service Provider) in this SAML connector with IdP-initiated flow.

After login to the Symantec IdP portal, when a user tries to click added Azure AD application connector, it redirects the user to configured Azure AD Assertion consumer URL(SAML endpoint). On the navigated page it displays the error message as 'Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in. AADSTS901004: Expected parameter estsrequest not found.'